# iOS Background Downloading using NSURLSessionConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, download, background

I have implemented the code to download chunks of size 1-2 MB in a batch of 20. Once the session completed the first 20 Download request it will set a new batch of 20 request in session. I have tested it on real device in console log and found this.

```
default 15:56:03.627080 +0800   xyz __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 14, 31 bytes): socket has been closed
default 15:56:03.671468 +0800   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- cmsmHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.xyz with pid '1447' is now Background Suspended. Background entitlement: NO
default 15:56:03.671804 +0800   mediaserverd    1067: pid 1447(xyz)
default 15:56:03.672156 +0800   mediaserverd    3138: sid:0x1a653, xyz(1447), 'prim' new state = Background Task Suspended
default 15:56:03.673578 +0800   locationd   Client com.xyz disconnected
default 15:56:03.694200 +0800   symptomsd   1447 com.xyz: BackgroundTaskSuspended (most elevated: BackgroundTaskSuspended)
default 15:56:03.716198 +0800   symptomsd   Entry, display name com.xyz uuid 02184FD5-F48B-3EF7-B2B6-98AB05145DB9 pid 1447 isFront 0
```

Sometimes got this issue.

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey`enter code here`
```

Code=2 is something related with device resources.

My question is can we download and request more files in background after downloading a batch. Or the background mode works only on ongoing request and suspend the app but continue downloading the file mentioned in sent task in batch.

Here is the code for BG task,

```
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        backgroundConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
    } else {
        backgroundConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"downloadmanager"];
    }


backgroundConfiguration.discretionary = YES;
backgroundConfiguration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = YES;
self.backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue];
```

Code to add NSURLRequest in BG Task,

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask;
            downloadTask = [self.backgroundSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
```

Background task handler in AppDelegate

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        DownloadManager.shared().backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = completionHandler
        print("background task called")
    }
```

After sending app in BG progress delegate stop printing the log after a while in console. And i can see it has downloaded the file partially.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    NSLog(@"Byte downlaoded %lld of %lld ", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download multiple requests in background queue it is so hard. So i recommend you to use Dispatch Groups. Follow this step below:
Step1: You can group 20 requests in one Dispatch Groups, in order to make your request balance you can set max concurrent request queue per connection. I think 2 concurrents is the best per connection.
Step2: When you use Dispatch Groups. It can notify after all 20 requests is completed and then you can create another Dispatch Groups for new 20 requests more.

Read this for Dispatch Groups https://www.allaboutswift.com/dev/2016/7/12/gcd-with-swfit3

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented background session to download multiple files in background but in serial manner.

But there are lots of challenges to achieve this functionality. If operating system uses more resources for other application, it will give priority to that app instead of your application so when you initiate the background session and you supposed set the remote timeout to 20 mins to download the file. It will throw you an error remote timeout after 20 mins and it will failed to download 2 mb file in background in which it will work smoothly when you run the application in foreground.

You can find the 2 mb file got downloaded in just few seconds in foreground mode contrary while application was in background it will throws an error(remote timeout) after 20 mins.

This is strange.... I found there is one solution in which when you try to download file in background mode make sure you connected to device to charging cable and you find that downloading will work like a charm.

Try this!!!!!!

If you have any query please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were downloading a file in one queue, destroyed the session and try to read it in another queue.

Comment: I am executing first 20 request in queue and once got the response of last request. Again call the same function to create queue and request for next 20 batch. Sometimes downloading stuck in between when m sending the app in background with aforementioned bug.

Comment: You have a background task prefroming all that?

Comment: Only the 20 chunk downloading code is in BG task. Maybe it will work if i put whole code in BG task where i am fetching next 20 chunk too. Let me try.

Comment: The app cannot work in the background endlessly, even with a background task - I hope you understand that. have you think about a silent push with a background data fetch?

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your time, Actually my handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession is not getting called in AppDelegate sometimes so i put beginBackgroundTask in applicationDidEnterBackground delegate. And now it is downloading the content for around 5-10 Min. Post that the BG task is suspended and we just post a local notification to open app in order to resume downloading.  Meanwhile m looking for the issue why "handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession" delegate is not getting called. I have bgmode enable in capabilities and in .plist. Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background
Please check that you implemented as it is described. From your explanation I understood that you download in a different way.